# Chartboost iOS: Get localized Video Ads?

Tags: ios, localization, chartboost

How to set up a campaign to get localized video ads? Is it possible?

If the user´s phone is us-language, show english videos, and if its a german phone, show german videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize the identity of the resource you use to load the video by wrapping the identifying string with `NSLocalizedString` macro (or function, in Swift). In your Localizable.strings you would specify the English identifier for the `en` locale and the German one for the `de` locale.

Comment: But Chartboost dont show localized videos. I think Chartboost is the problem?